# Каким образом сделать такую проверку по массиву JS?

Tags: javascript

Добрый день есть такой массив

```
var arrayPositions = [493.19998931884766, 916.5999755859375, 1340, 1763.3999633789062, 2186.7999877929688, 2916.2001342773438, 3339.6000366210938, 4068.9999389648438, 4492.400085449219, 4915.799987792969]
```

10 координат.
Это координаты элементов что я получаю через цикл each.
У Jquery есть такая функция

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  });
```

**Вопрос**

Каким образом можно сделать такую проверку, что если var scroll имеет значения больше 0 элемента но меньше 1 , я получаю индекс 0 элемента. Если к примеру число больше 4 элемента но меньше 5 я получаю его индекс

И насколько правильно делать такую проверку в Window.Scroll. функцию. Ведь проверка будет каждый раз при каждом px

Comment: а если меньше нулевого элемента? какой индекс должен возвращаться?

Comment: Зачем использовать массив ?

Comment: @Grundy Если меньше 0 ничего, либо же условия там console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если решать в лоб:

```js
const points = [1.5, 5.5, 8.5];

function getIndex(value, points) {
  for (let i = points.length; i >= 0; --i) {
    const point = points[i];
    if (point <= value) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}

for (let i=0; i<10; ++i) {
  console.log(i, getIndex(i, points));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

метод [`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) возвращает `index` первого элемента удовлетворяющего условию.

Таким образом можно проверить, какой из элементов `больше` переданного параметра, и из полученного индекса вычесть единицу.

```
var index = arrayPositions.findIndex(el=>el<scroll);
if(index == 0) { // если значение меньше нулевого элемента
    // ...
}

if (index == -1) { // если в массиве нет значения больше заданного
    index = arrayPositions.length-1; // индекс последнего элемента
}
```